# Undefined method `price_workshops_attributes' - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using angularjs in my form and I need to include data in my json for my `ng-init`, but it marks me an error, how can I resolve this error?
I need it because I'm using nested attributes

```
<%= form_for [:client, @workshop_manager], class: 'form-horizontal',
  :multipart => true, html: {
    :onsubmit => 'return false;',
    "ng-init" => "workshop_manager="+@workshop_manager.to_json({
      :include => [:price_workshops_attributes]
    })
  } do |f| %>
```

My error:

> `NoMethodError` - undefined method `price_workshops_attributes` for `#<WorkshopManager:0x000000000e8b0ac0>`

Comment: @workshop_manager is this an AR object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from `to_json` trying to call `price_workshops_attributes` method which does not exist on model, only `price_workshops_attributes=` is defined when you define it with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :price_workshops`.

You can define it youself with something like:

```
def price_workshops_attributes
  price_workshops.map{|price_workshop|
    # here you may need to manually specify needed fields
    price_workshop.as_json
  }
end
```